# Error in itext package

Tags: java, swing, itext

I downloaded `itext-1.3` and placed into lib folder of `jdk 1.6.0` . And added the lib folder as the CLASSPATH in system variables.

But while I run the program I get the error:

> package com.itextpdf.text does not exist.

Similarly for all other packages too. What mistake I made?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * First iText example: Hello World.
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "E:/hello.pdf";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF file: hello.pdf
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
        new HelloWorld().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException 
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: windows or linux? And are you using an IDE?

Comment: @Windows. No, I don't use an IDE and for editor, I use Notepad.

Comment: Where did you download itext 1.3? The itext 1.3.* versions date from 2005 are hopelessly outdated. You wouldn't be able to to use them in the code above anyway, because anything below version 5.0.0 is com.lowagie, starting with 5.0.0 it was renamed to com.itextpdf. You can download itext from our GitHub page: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't add anything to the JVM/JDK lib or ext folders unless you instructed to do so explicitly

Depending on you development environment (& your future intentions), you should place the libraries in a location best suited to it, for example, in a lib directory within you project folder (but outside of the source).

You should either add a class-path dependence into the projects Jar manifest (check out [Adding Classes to JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)) or use the `-cp` parameter on the command line to execute the program. You should use the -classpath option of the javac to compile the program

As for the development environment, that depends on what you are using

**Special note**

Each Jar file needs to be referenced separately on the Classpath, you can not specify a folder & expect the JVM to scan its contents for Jar files, only works for classes

**UPDATED WITH COMPILE EXECUTE EXAMPLE**

I download iText 5.3.1.  From the zip file I extracted:

- itextpdf-5.3.1.jar
- itext-pdfa-5.3.1.jar
- itext-xtra-5.3.1.jar

And placed them in an easy to reach location.

I downloaded the [HelloWorld example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12) from the iText in Action website.  I placed this in the `src` directory under the same location as the Jar's

I modified the code so that the resulting PDF would be created in the current working directory

```
public static final String RESULT = "hello.pdf";
```

I compiled the example with `javac.exe -cp d:\hold\itextpdf-5.3.1.jar;d:\hold\itext-pdfa-5.3.1.jar;d:\hold\itext-xtra-5.3.1.jar -d . src\HelloWorld.java` (compiled in `d:\hold`)

This created the HelloWorld class in part1\chapter01 in `D:\hold`

I then executed the example with `java -cp d:\hold\itextpdf-5.3.1.jar;d:\hold\itext-pdfa-5.3.1.jar;d:\hold\itext-xtra-5.3.1.jar;d:\hold part1.chapter01.HelloWorld`

This resulted in the creation of `hello.pdf` in the current directory (`D:\hold`)

Comment: My CLASSPATH now is `.;D:\itext-1.3.jar` . Though I have referenced it separately, it doesn't work.

Comment: What development environment? What doesn't work, compilation or run?

Comment: I use just Notepad, Sir. Compilation doesn't work. I even tried `javac -cp ".;D:\itext-1.3.jar" Hello.java`

Comment: It gets compiled perfectly. :) Thanks. But while executing it says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/Element` for the very same program you have tried on. I executed as java HelloWorld. Is that right? I also changed path to pdf as `"E:/hello.pdf"`

Comment: Make sure the java Classpath is the same used with the javac

Comment: Do you mean to include that -cp followed by jar files , while executing too? I tried that, but error is same, Sir.

Comment: Could add the source code you trying to compile/run to the original post

Comment: Added it Sir. It is the same program you were trying.

Comment: Compiled and executed without issue, please see update.  A small piece of advice, find a IDE you like an use it.  The commandline is unforgiving and until you truly understand it, it's not really a requirement that you use it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. It was a clear explanation. Now, it works fine. Anyways, is it possible to create a manifest file, to include the compiling command (javac -cp ...) and execution code?

Comment: Sure, manifest files are only useful in Jar files. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html & http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. You have helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to do anything on jdk library. Just need to give path of itext jar files, to the java by using classpath.

I also suffer from the same problem but having itext 5.5.3.
In my case I create a **lib** folder in parallel to my working folder.
In **lib** folder I put all the three jar files *(itextpdf-5.5.3.jar, itext-pdfa-5.5.3.jar, itext-xtra-5.5.3.jar).*
Don't waste time in giving the path of each jar file separately at the time of compiling and running the code.

I compiled the code, eg1.java(c:\ItextPractise\code\eg1.java) with

`javac -classpath c:\ItextPractise\lib\*;. eg1.java`

and run using

`java -classpath c:\ItextPractise\lib\*;. eg1` (eg1 is the name of main class in my case)

You may know more about classpath from [OracleOfficialPage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Answer (score -1):

this might be as a result of the absence of the itext library in your project. simply download the itext jar file and add it to your project library

Comment: Read @MadProgrammer's answer, the OP confirmed that it worked for him.